# Enviar parametros desde la vista al controlador en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, razor

Al momento de recibir los parámetros en el Controlador desde la Vista, los mismo llegan nulos, en la Vista tengo el siguiente código:

```
@model Syc.Visitantes.Dominio.Entidades.Usuario

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Crear Usuario";
}

<h2>Crear Usuario</h2>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Volver", "Index")
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Nombre</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Correo</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Correo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Correo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Código de Acceso</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.CodigoAcceso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.CodigoAcceso, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Clave de Acceso</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ClaveAcceso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.ClaveAcceso, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Rol</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("RolId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.RolId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })    
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">            
            @Html.ActionLink("Crear", "Crear", "Usuarios")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Y este es el código del Controlador:

```
    using Syc.Visitantes.Aplicacion.Controladores;
    using Syc.Visitantes.Dominio.Entidades;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Visitantes.Controllers
    {
        public class UsuariosController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Crear([Bind(Include = "Nombre,Correo,CodigoAcceso,ClaveAcceso,RolId")] Usuario usuario)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    UsuarioControlador controlador = new UsuarioControlador();
                    Usuario usuarioCreador = new Usuario();
                    controlador.Crear(usuario);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(usuario);
            }
    }
}
```

Pero al verificar me doy cuenta de que **usuario** recibe los valores nulos desde la vista.

Comment: Es posible que aqui deba ir en singular `usuario`? -> `@Html.ActionLink("Crear", "Crear", "Usuarios")`

Comment: Has intentado usar la etiqueta [FromBody]? o Request.Form["nombre_del_campo"] para los valores?

Comment: Pikoh de hecho también me hice esa pregunta y lo intenté, pero debe ir en plurar ya que asi es el nombre del Controlador.

Comment: M_Armendariz voy a probar con lo que dices, en qué parte del código pruebo con esas etiquetas?

Comment: Porque no cambias esto **@Html.ActionLink("Crear", "Crear", "Usuarios")** por un simple <input type="submit" value="Aceptar" />

Comment: Por cierto, es importante saber que versión de asp.net.mvc estás usando. Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201341)

Comment: Pero colocando el input, cómo indico qué método del controlador Usuarios ejecutar? El método que debo ejecutar se llama Crear.

Comment: ¿Sólo tienes definido un método Crear? Quiero decir, el que se ve en tu código no está decorado con el atributo HttpPost ¿es porque lo has omitido al copiar aquí o realmente no lo tienes definido? Si lo decoras con el Post no te va a enlazar los valores porque ni siquiera va a evaluar el body

Comment: Si lo omití al copiar, perdón, ya que estaba comentado. Ya lo descomenté (este código [HttpPost] esta justo antes del método Crear), coloqué en la vista el input (<input type="submit" value="Crear"  />) Pero al hacer click en el input no llama al controlador. Al usar el input cómo le indico qué controlador llamar y qué método de ese controlador usar?

Comment: En tu BeginForm puedes indicar a que metodo de tu controladora haras el submit

Comment: Correcto, coloqué en el BeginForm la referencia al método y el controlador a utilizar (@using (Html.BeginForm("Crear", "Usuarios", FormMethod.Post))) y funcionó correctamente, ya llegan los valores.

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero que puedo comentar es que no uses en la linea

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Nombre, ...
```

Model con la M mayuscula, recuerda que c# es key-sensitive, por lo que no referencias al `model` del lambda, utiliza

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, ...
```

model con minuscula

Por otro lado el `@Html.ActionLink` no realiza un post al action, deberias definir un button de submit para enviar los datos.

Basicametne se tiene dos action, uno que sea `GET` para cargar la view cuando ingresas y uno `POST` donde recibes el submit del form

```
public class UsuariosController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Crear()
    {
        //aqui instancia un usuario por defecto para el model
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        return View(usuario);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Crear(Usuario usuario)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UsuarioControlador controlador = new UsuarioControlador();
            Usuario usuarioCreador = new Usuario();
            controlador.Crear(usuario);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(usuario);
    }


}
```

Pero para recibir el post necesitas un boton del `type="submit"` y no un action link